# extract child node to create XML with respective parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

I have an input XML like following structure.

```
<Root>
    <STDS>
        <DEPT>111</DEPT>
        <COD>123</COD>
        <PIN>100</PIN>
    </STDS>
    <STDS>
        <DEPT>222</DEPT>
        <COD>234</COD>
        <PIN>200</PIN>
        <DETS>
            <NAM>ABC</NAM>
            <AGE>20</AGE>
        </DETS>
    </STDS>
    <STDS>
        <DEPT>333</DEPT>
        <COD>345</COD>
        <PIN>300</PIN>
        <DETS>
            <NAM>XYZ</NAM>
            <AGE>21</AGE>
        </DETS>
        <DETS>
            <NAM>ZZZ</NAM>
            <AGE>21</AGE>
        </DETS>
    </STDS>
</Root>
```

I'm using the following code to solve this. I'm using a for-each loop all convert all STDS into  while another for-each is extracting the child DETS and merging it with parent DETS nodes. But due to for-each, it's giving all the nodes together. while child nodes(DETS) are required be just below the respective parent node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 userCSharp" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="Students" xmlns:s0="STDS" xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root" />
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/s0:Root">
    <ns0:Students>

      <xsl:for-each select="s0:Root/s0:STDS">
       <Students>
            <Department>
                <xsl:value-of select="s0:DEPT" />
            </Department>
            <Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="s0:COD" />
            </Code>
            <Pin>
                <xsl:value-of select="s0:PIN" /></Pin>
            <Details>
                <Name><xsl:value-of select="NAM" /></Name>
                <Age><xsl:value-of select="AGE" /></Age>
            </Details>
        </Students>
      </xsl:for-each>

     <xsl:for-each select="s0:STDS/s0:DETS">
        <Students>
            <Department>
                <xsl:value-of select="../DEPT" />
            </Department>
            <Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="../COD" />
            </Code>
            <Pin>
                <xsl:value-of select="../PIN" />
            </Pin>
            <Details>
                <Name><xsl:value-of select="s0:NAM" /></Name>
                <Age><xsl:value-of select="s0:AGE" /></Age>
            </Details>
        </Students>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

I'm getting the following output. Due to for-each all the extracted nodes are at the end.

```
<Students>
    <Department>222</Department>
    <Code>234</Code>
    <Pin>200</Pin>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>333</Department>
    <Code>345</Code>
    <Pin>300</Pin>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>222</Department>
    <Code>234</Code>
    <Pin>200</Pin>
    <Details>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Age>20</Age>
    </Details>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>333</Department>
    <Code>345</Code>
    <Pin>300</Pin>
    <Details>
        <Name>XYZ</Name>
        <Age>21</Age>
    </Details>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>333</Department>
    <Code>345</Code>
    <Pin>300</Pin>
    <Details>
        <Name>ZZZ</Name>
        <Age>21</Age>
    </Details>
</Students>
```

While the expected output is following.

```
<Students>
    <Department>111</Department>
    <Code>123</Code>
    <Pin>100</Pin>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>222</Department>
    <Code>234</Code>
    <Pin>200</Pin>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>222</Department>
    <Code>234</Code>
    <Pin>200</Pin>
    <Details>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Age>20</Age>
    </Details>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>333</Department>
    <Code>345</Code>
    <Pin>300</Pin>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>333</Department>
    <Code>345</Code>
    <Pin>300</Pin>
    <Details>
        <Name>XYZ</Name>
        <Age>21</Age>
    </Details>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>333</Department>
    <Code>345</Code>
    <Pin>300</Pin>
    <Details>
        <Name>ZZZ</Name>
        <Age>21</Age>
    </Details>
</Students>
```

Comment: You should not be using custom Xslt for this.  Or rather, you 100% do not need custom Xlst for this.  It's very, very easy in the Mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rather strange requirement - but it can be achieved rather easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:for-each select="STDS">
        <xsl:variable name="common">
            <Department>
                <xsl:value-of select="DEPT" />
            </Department>
            <Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="COD" />
            </Code>
            <Pin>
                <xsl:value-of select="PIN" />
            </Pin>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- DEPARTMENT -->
        <Students>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$common"/>
        </Students>
        <!-- STUDENTS -->
        <xsl:for-each select="DETS">
            <Students>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$common"/>
                <Details>
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NAM" />
                    </Name>
                    <Age>   
                        <xsl:value-of select="AGE" />
                    </Age>
                </Details>
            </Students>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the result is an XML fragment (no single root element).

Comment: @Parfait I downvoted because the question is tagged 'biztalk' so this is **not a good answer for BizTalk**.  There is a much easier and proper way to do this in BizTalk.

Comment: But it is also tagged XSLT which we are providing such a solution. Moreover the OP shows an attempted XSLT solution (not BizTalk).

Comment: @Parfait Yes, because BizTalk supports using Xslt for outlier purposes.  This case is in no way an outlier and is supported directly by the tools which is why an Xslt Answer is not a proper BizTalk answer, sorry, that's just how it is.  OP is probably just unfamiliar with the Looping Functoid which does exactly what they're looking for.  This Answer my be technically correct, but **not for BizTalk** as it's just adding unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 1):

Consider avoiding the use of multiple `xsl:for-each` (usually a paradigm of application layer languages using loops not XSLT's recursive style) and handle needs with templates conditionally applying the *Details* node if it exists:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="STDS"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="STDS">
    <Students>    
      <Department><xsl:value-of select="DEPT"/></Department>
      <Code><xsl:value-of select="COD"/></Code>
      <Pin><xsl:value-of select="PIN"/></Pin>
    </Students>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DETS"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DETS">
    <Students>    
      <Department><xsl:value-of select="../DEPT"/></Department>
      <Code><xsl:value-of select="../COD"/></Code>
      <Pin><xsl:value-of select="../PIN"/></Pin>
      <Details>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="NAM"/></Name>
        <Age><xsl:value-of select="AGE"/></Age>
     </Details>
     </Students>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWj/3)

Comment: Because of your reluctance to use `xsl:for-each` you are forced to repeat the same code in both templates + add unnecessary trips up and down the tree.

Comment: Understood. OP's needs is to duplicate nodes. May return with DRY-er solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the Mapper all you need to do is **connect `<DETS>` to `<Students>` through a Looping Functoid**.

That's all, no custom xslt required.

One Note:  Depending on the Schema composition, you may need another Looping Functoid from `<STDS>` to `<Student>`.  It's very easy to try different combinations.

While they maybe technically correct, the Xsl Answers are not the proper way to do this in **BizTalk**.